# How to use a phrase as HotString in AutoHotkey - including spaces in HotString

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way to include a space in the HotString and still have the space trigger the HotString replacement? For example:

```
::_u_::_you_  <--where the underscores are actually space chars
```

or

```
:*:_fo_r::_for_  <--where the underscores are actually space chars
```

so if I typed

> StackOverflow is a great place **fo r**answers!

it would be changed to

> StackOverflow is a great place **for** answers!

I'm looking for a way to define a phrase as the hotstring really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange. I tried escaping with `` `s `` but that didn't work. The [docs](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) say two things:

> To send an extra space or tab after a replacement, include the space or tab at the end of the replacement but make the last character an accent/backtick (`). For example:

```
:*:btw::By the way `
```

and

> Spaces and tabs are treated literally within hotstring definitions. For example, the following would produce two different results: `::btw::by the way` and `::btw:: by the way`

So, I would think this should work:

```
:*: fo r:: for `
```

That works in notepad, but only if I try it at the start of a line. Mid-sentence it fails.

You may be forced to use one of the user-created dynamic regex hotstring libraries.

Using [this library](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/98728-dynamic-hotstrings/), this works:

```
#include Hotstring.ahk
Hotstring(" fo r", " for ")
```

---

edit:

I asked on the AHK forums, and the `?` option should do it:

```
:*?: fo r:: for `
```

Comment: Sweet.  `:*?: fo r:: for ` ` works. Just have to be careful since the *? will work anywhere within a word and without an ending character, but it does what I was looking for. Thanks mikew

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
:*: fo r::
SetKeyDelay, -1
Send for{space}
return
```